# MySQL .IBD file modified accidentaly the cause was database corruption how to recover it

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2013

I have MySQL runs as docker image. Few days ago one of my colleague edited .ibd file and the result is corrupted database. When we try to access tables in that database MySQL database crushes. Here i added picture of corrupted file. How to recover that .ibd file?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9H1U.png)

Comment: Have you tried running the server against a copy of the backed-up data dir, using mysqldump to export it, then import the file when running the server against the real (new) data dir?

Comment: The sad part of this incident is all procedure done without backup.